# NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError while using PCML Connector when enabling DEBUG log level WSO2 EI 6.1.1

Tags: log4j, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I use [AS400 PCML Connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/AS400+PCML+Connector) in Wso2 EI 6.1.1 to call AS400-DB2 remote program calls.

**Issue:**
If DEBUG level log enabled for *rootlogger*  in log4j.properties(wso2ei-6.1.1\conf)
,PCML call not works and throws an error: NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception.

complete stack-trace:

> ERROR - NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.ibm.as400.access.SocketProperties.getLoginTimeout()I
>           at org.wso2.carbon.connector.pcml.AS400Initialize.getSocketProperties(AS400Initialize.java:297)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.connector.pcml.AS400Initialize.getConnectionPool(AS400Initialize.java:216)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.connector.pcml.AS400Initialize.connect(AS400Initialize.java:78)
>           at org.wso2.carbon.connector.core.AbstractConnector.mediate(AbstractConnector.java:32)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:84)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:104)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:148)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:84)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:104)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:148)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:84)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.TemplateMediator.mediate(TemplateMediator.java:104)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:148)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.template.InvokeMediator.mediate(InvokeMediator.java:84)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:169)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:97)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:59)
>           at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
>           at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:343)
>           at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:399)
>           at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcess(RESTRequestHandler.java:123)
>           at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:101)
>           at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:69)
>           at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:304)
>           at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:78)
>           at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:326)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:372)
>           at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
>           at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

sample PCML file :

```
<pcml version="4.0">
 <program name="Validate" path="/QSYS.LIB/SVDGDG.LIB/PEB0012.PGM">
 <data name="inputNIC" type="char" length="15" usage="input" />
 <data name="inputIAC" type="char" length="4" usage="input" />
 <data name="outputStatusCode" type="char" length="1" usage="output" />
 </program>
</pcml>
```

Enabled DEBUG log level in log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CARBON_CONSOLE, CARBON_LOGFILE, CARBON_MEMORY, CARBON_SYS_LOG, ERROR_LOGFILE
```

PCML connector configuration applied similar to this link:https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+AS400+PCML+Connector+Operations

AS400 driver implementation lib:jt400

**Note:**

- If DEBUG level log changed to higher level(info/error) PCML call
  works fine
- my actual requirement is to apply [per-API DEBUG logs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Per-API+Logs+in+WSO2+ESB).Since the above
  issue raised for [per-API DEBUG logs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Per-API+Logs+in+WSO2+ESB),I tried to globally enable DEBUG level log in root
  logger(disabled per -API logs).but issue remains same.
- enabling wire-logs not fulfills my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error caused due to jt400.jar versioning problem.
issue can be fixed by using latest version of jt400.jar(version 8.5 for now).